# How and where to add dependencies on Bonita's Jboss Bundle

Tags: java, jboss, bundle, bonita

I've designed my process with Bonita BPM Studio and now I wanna deploy it on Jboss bundle.

In Bonita BPM when you run a process, Bonita BPM generates a war file and this war file is transmited to a Tomcat server who is embedded in Bonita BPM Studio.

In my process, there is a task who parse xml files. To do this, I've added JDOM2 in classpath of Tomcat.

And now, when I wanna deploy my application with Jboss bundle (by importing bar file) I throw an exception because JDOM2 isn't resolved in JBOSS AS7. I've tried [this how to](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-deploy/configuring-jboss-shared-libs) but doesn't work.

Someone could help me by telling me where and how to add JDOM2 in Bonita's JBoss bundle please ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide a clear answer, I would like to first correct a couple of your statements.

Bonita BPM does not generate a WAR file.
Bonita relies on a WAR for its Engine and its Portal web application.
The WAR file is only deployed once at server installation time.

After that, when the Java server is running, processes are deployed to the Bonita Engine as BAR files.

If you want to use dependencies such as JDOM2 in your process, you should not add these libraries directly into the Java server.
Instead, use to the Studio to add them in the process configuration so that the process BAR includes them.
See this documentation page for more details:
http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/product-bos-sp/process-configuration

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hello POZ and thank you for your response. I've tried to add JDOM2 in processes's dependencies but when I run my process I throw 'javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found' it occurs when more than once SAX parsers have been loaded by ClassLoader. And the only solution I've found is to add JDOM2 in classpath's Java Server.